# Google Tag Manager - make id dynamic

Tags: google-tag-manager

I need to implement google tag manager in my application. It is a multi tenant application with a separate configuration system.

I have setup google tag manager and analytics. I am adding following code snippet just below my body page:-

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript>
    <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
<script>
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

However I need to dynamically specify the id('GTM-XXXX') based on which site is loaded. Is there a way to mention id in above code snippet at runtime/dynamically? I need to replace/change id in the iframe and in the script.

Also note that its an angularJS front end

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I am using React, my configuration is loaded after <Head> tag is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iframe and the script are mutually exclusive; one will occur when the user has Javascript enabled (basically all the time), and the other when they don't (in which situation Google Tag Manager will do its best, but probably won't track all that well. You can construct separate solutions for each.

You just need to write a small function that, depending on some identifiable variable, decided which GTM code to deploy, and replaces either that segment of code, or the iframe src respectively.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. GTM tag is implemented in the <Head> & <Body>. I am using react and load my configuration based on hostname. However this hostname check runs after the HTML in index.js is loaded. How exactly would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I could be wrong here, But you can just store a global variable for the current page you're on (i.e., window.pageGTM = GTM-XXXXX) and then place that variable inside the container snippet.